Despite using 'DrissionPage' library, Why I faced "This site can't be reached" issue
Can you please help me to solve this issue?
Why this code doesn't work. Despite using drissionpage library for scraping a website. I can't submit this form automatically though I can fill up the form. The site's form page
from DrissionPage import ChromiumPage
from time import sleep


page = ChromiumPage()

page.get('https://apps.hcr.ny.gov/BuildingSearch/')

page.ele('hashtag#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_zipCodeSearchLinkButton').click()
sleep(2)

page.ele('xpath://*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_countyListDropDown"]/optgroup[1]/option[1]').click()
sleep(2)
page.ele('xpath://*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_zipCodesDropDown"]/option[2]').click()
sleep(2)
page.ele('hashtag#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_submitZipCodeButton').click()

sleep(5)
page.quit()


Please run the script to test.
I tried the script to run, it works till the filling up form, but after clicking submit button I got this image:Page after submitting the form.
I expect that the script automatically submit the form successfully and will collect the data after submitting the form. I tried with selenium but it failed to scrape this js based website, for this I choose 'DrissionPage' library. Please help me to resolve this issue.
